# Animate in both ways

Tags: html, css

I'm using animista animations, and I would like to achieve that button scale in left on div block hover and in case I move mouse out of the div block, for the button to scale out left.

Here is my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/30sfzy6n/3/ .

```
<div class="element">
 <button>
  +
 </button>
</div>

.element {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}

.element:hover button {
  display: flex;
    -webkit-animation: scale-in-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
            animation: scale-in-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

.element button {
  display: none;
    -webkit-animation: scale-out-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
            animation: scale-out-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
* Generated by Animista on 2018-8-30 14:38:13
* w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
* ---------------------------------------------- */
@-webkit-keyframes scale-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}@keyframes scale-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}
@-webkit-keyframes scale-out-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}@keyframes scale-out-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}
```

Display: none and display: flex is a mandatory for me.

Comment: What is the expected outcome? To have the + button appear both on the left and right side of the div upon hovering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not give `display: none` for the scaling out animation. It immediately hides the button without the animation.

Instead, you could use javascript to set `display: none` after a specific timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use display:none property. Display none; not accept animation property.

```
<div class="element">
  <button>
  +
 </button>
</div>

.element {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}

.element:hover button {
  display: flex;
    -webkit-animation: scale-in-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
            animation: scale-in-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

.element button {
    -webkit-animation: scale-out-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
            animation: scale-out-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
* Generated by Animista on 2018-8-30 14:38:13
* w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
* ---------------------------------------------- */
@-webkit-keyframes scale-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}@keyframes scale-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}
@-webkit-keyframes scale-out-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}@keyframes scale-out-left{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform-origin:0 50%;opacity:1}}
```